# Union all doens't seem to be working as expected. Returning less rows

Tags: mysql, database, union, union-all

Sorry for this newbie question but i have been tearing my hair out for the past few hours on something that couldn't be any simpler.

I have a table (single_elim):

```
id_tournament   phase   player1    player2
    1             1        1         2
    1             1        3         4
    1             1        5         10
```

and i am trying to write a query that given a player gives me his opponent.
Unfortunately i can't know if the player will be in the player1 column or the player 2 (but i know they are mutually exclusive) column so i expected a possible solution to be:

```
SELECT p AS opponent FROM (

    (
      SELECT player1 as p FROM single_elim
      WHERE
          id_tournament = 1 AND
          phase = 1 AND
          player2 = 4

    ) UNION ALL (

      SELECT player2 as p FROM single_elim
      WHERE
          id_tournament = 1 AND
          phase = 1 AND
          player1 = 4
    )

) x;
```

However the statement return 0 rows.

If i run the single statement:

```
SELECT player1 as p FROM single_elim
    WHERE
        id_tournament = 1 AND
        phase = 1 AND
        player2 = 4
```

Assuming that player2 will be in column 4 then it works and i get a one row result with p = 3.
I have also tried with `UNION` and i have also tried different kinds of querys that i would have expected to work, my conclusion is that i am missing something fundamental about how union works, however after some research i haven't managed to figure it out.

Another example of query that worked alone but not with a union was:

```
SELECT * FROM (

        SELECT COUNT(*) as n, player2 as p FROM helper
        WHERE id_tournament = 1 AND player1 = 4 AND phase = 1

    ) UNION ALL (

        SELECT COUNT(*) as n, player1 as p FROM helper
        WHERE id_tournament = 1 AND player2 = 4 AND phase = 1

    )
) x WHERE n = 1;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing does seem odd, the first UNION should have returned one row. (Are the data values integer types or string types?)

However, you shouldn't need UNION unless this is an enormous table where you need to optimize index use as much as possible.

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN player1 = 4 THEN player2 ELSE player1 END as p 
  FROM single_elim
  WHERE id_tournament = 1 
     AND phase = 1 
     AND (player1 = 4 OR player2 = 4)
  ;
```

Comment: Tha values are all Ints.
Yes your solution works! And it seems to be much more elegant. thanks alot.
I figured it must be a bug in mySql 5.6 but have not found any indication of it around which is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think the brackets are messing it up. In any case, you don't need the wrapping select query, the union is enough. this one works well:

```
SELECT player1 as p FROM single_elim
  WHERE
      id_tournament = 1 AND
      phase = 2 AND
      player2 = 4
UNION ALL
  SELECT player2 as p FROM single_elim
  WHERE
      id_tournament = 1 AND
      phase = 2 AND
      player1 = 4;
```